# How to refresh cloud firebase database, sometimes it shows old values

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

When I open the page sometimes it shows old values of cloud firebase so for that I need when activity opens firstly it should refresh and then proceed.
I tried to refresh it but it's not working.

This is the code I have tried:

```
// some code before ...
mfirestore.collection("Design1").addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onEvent(QuerySnapshot documentSnapshots, FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
        for (DocumentChange doc : documentSnapshots.getDocumentChanges()) {
            if (doc.getType() == DocumentChange.Type.ADDED) {
                Users users = doc.getDocument().toObject(Users.class);
                usersList.add(users);
                usersrecycleradapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    }
});

Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Pic1.this,Cart1.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
mfirestore.collection("Extraimage").document("Design1").get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
        String image1 = documentSnapshot.getString("image1");
        Glide.with(Pic1.this).load(image1).into(imageView);
    }
});

context();
// some code after...
```

Definitions of related methods:

```
public void context(){
    refresh(1000);
}

private void refresh(int millisecond) {
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    final Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            context();
        }

    };
    handler.postDelayed(runnable, millisecond);
}
```

Comment: You can use firestore recycler view to implement what you want a simple google search will point you to this

Comment: firestore recyclerview i had used

Comment: but when i update data in cloud database it not changes like realtime database

Comment: it shows sometimes old values

Answer (score 0):

I think activity view is not getting updated with data change.  You can try using view model or RxJava.

Comment: How to refresh current Activity 1 time after load? My code refresh the activity, but in Loop.